# PHP: Subtracting Days from easter_date() to calculate Ash Wednesday

Tags: php, date, time

I am trying to calculate the date for Ash Wednesday with PHP, but I am running into an unusual problem.

- Ash Wednesday is celebrated **46 days** before Easter.
- There are **86400** seconds in a day.
- 46 * 86400 = 3974400
- Therefore, Ash Wednesday is **3974400 seconds** before Easter.

`easter_date()` is a built in PHP function that returns the Unix timestamp for midnight on Easter of the current year.

`date('F d, Y', easter_date())` returns `March 27, 2016`, which is **correct**.

**Now... this is where the problem begins.**

As a result, one would assume that `date('F d, Y', easter_date() - 3974400)` returns `February 10, 2016`, right?

**Wrong.**

The actual result is `February 09, 2016`, which is one day before Ash Wednesday.

Could this be because 2016 is a leap year? Is this some sort of known issue with `easter_date()`? Or am I just doing something wrong?

> **Edit:** I am using PHP Version **5.5.9-1ubuntu4.16** for the record.

Comment: Its seems like its php version issue. Its working fine with my system. So dont use `easter_date()` and better to use `strtotime()`

Comment: Works fine: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/90872fd92fa4b23ca3a2559bc8b136d2b5b85b5e

Comment: It's more likely to be a daylight savings adjustment... what date did the clocks change for DST in your (servers) timezone? Because subtracting `3974400` seconds is making some very explicit assumptions about the number of hours in a day, assumptions that break twice a year when daylight savings are involved

Comment: @Justinas I looked at the link, and it actually doesn't work. It still returns February 09, 2016, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Try this code,

```
    <?php     
    // Determine the date of Easter for a given year.
    function EasterDate($EasterYear)
    {
        $goldenNumber = fmod($EasterYear, 19) + 1;     
        if ($EasterYear <= 1752)
        {
            $dominicalNumber = fmod($EasterYear + ($EasterYear / 4) + 5, 7);
            $paschalFullMoon = fmod(3 - (11 * $goldenNumber) - 7, 30);
        }
        else
        {
            $dominicalNumber = fmod($EasterYear + ($EasterYear / 4) - ($EasterYear / 100) + ($EasterYear / 400), 7);
            $solarCorrection = ($EasterYear - 1600) / 100 - ($EasterYear - 1600) / 400;
            $lunarCorrection = ((($EasterYear - 1400) / 100) * 8) / 25;
            $paschalFullMoon = fmod(3 - 11 * $goldenNumber + $solarCorrection - $lunarCorrection, 30);
        }     
        while ($dominicalNumber < 0)
        {
            $dominicalNumber += 7;
        }     
        while ($paschalFullMoon < 0)
        {
            $paschalFullMoon += 30;
        }     
        if ($paschalFullMoon == 29 || ($paschalFullMoon == 28 && $goldenNumber > 11))
        {
            $paschalFullMoon--;
        }     
        $difference = fmod(4 - $paschalFullMoon - $dominicalNumber, 7);     
        if ($difference < 0)
        {
            $difference += 7;
        }     
        $dayEaster = $paschalFullMoon + $difference + 1;     
        if ($dayEaster < 11)
        {            
            $EasterDate = mktime(0, 0, 0, 3, $dayEaster + 21, $EasterYear);
        }
        else
        {
            $EasterDate = mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, $dayEaster - 10, $EasterYear);
        }     
        return $EasterDate;
    } 
    // Requires EasterDate()
    function dateAshWednesday($EasterYear)
    {
        $easter = getDate(EasterDate($EasterYear));
        return mktime(0, 0, 0, $easter['mon'], $easter['mday'] - 46, $easter['year']);
    }     
    // Unit tests
     $testYear = 2016;
     echo "Ash Wednesday: " . date("j F Y", dateAshWednesday($testYear)) . "<br>";
     echo "Easter: " . date("j F Y", EasterDate($testYear)) . "<br>";
?>
```